# PhoneGap File Transfer Image submit form

Tags: android, image, forms, cordova, file-transfer

im stumped on how to get the Filetransfer APi to work as part of a submit form. Currently you select a picture and its automatically sent to the server however for the application i need other data sending with it. I have the other parts working correctly i need which is just text/option based however im stumped with the image.

atm im just looking at zac vineyards code example

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4    /strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>File Transfer Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    function onDeviceReady() {
// Do cool things here...
    }

    function getImage() {
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
alert('get picture failed');
},{
quality: 50,
destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
}
        );

    }

    function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

        var params = new Object();
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";

        options.params = params;
        options.chunkedMode = false;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, "http://yourdomain.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);
    }

    function win(r) {
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        console.log("Response = " + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
        alert(r.response);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " = error.code);
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="getImage();">Upload a Photo</button>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone would have any ideas it would be much appriciated. Ive tried many different things. I have had it working on a desktop platform but when i use my phone which is Android if thats anything to do with it. It doesnt work. Thanks

Comment: You're already sending extra data through the options object. Look at the options.params object.

Answer (score 0):

You add the key/value pairs you want to send along as members of the "params" object. Say if you wanted to send uid=1234 and server=na then you'd do:

```
var params = new Object();
params.uid = "1234";
params.server = "na";
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can send other data say objetId and image like that:

```
       options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1)+".jpg";       
       var upload_url="http:YourDomain.com 
       /upload?token="+objectId+"&filenaam="+options.fileName;
        ft.upload(imageURI, upload_url, win, fail, options);
```